# pattern matching using grep or awk

Tags: awk, grep

Considering the following line of text:

```
abc/xyz-ibl.txt-234-   "simple", /* col */
```

How can I extract `xyz-ibl.txt` and `simple` from the above text using regular expressions. Filename can be anything but it always have an extension of `.txt` and `simple` also can be anything but is always followed by `, /* col */`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the filename:

```
grep -oP "\b[^/]*\.txt"
```

And this will get you `simple`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=")[^"]*(?="\s*,\s*/\*\s*col\s*\*/)'
```

And this will get you both:

```
grep -oP '\b[^/]*\.txt|(?<=")[^"]*(?="\s*,\s*/\*\s*col\s*\*/)'
```

Example:

```
s='abc/xyz-ibl.txt-234-   "simple", /* col */'
echo "$s" |grep -oP "\b[^/]*\.txt"
echo "$s" |grep -oP '(?<=")[^"]*(?="\s*,\s*/\*\s*col\s*\*/)'
```

Output:

```
xyz-ibl.txt
simple
```

Note: `-P` is for Perl regex.

EDIT:

According to your comment, if you want to extract them if only both of them matches, then better use `sed` than `grep`.

Using `sed` with extended regex:

```
echo "$s" |sed -nr 's#.*/(\b[^/]+\.txt).*"([^"]*)*"\s*,\s*/\*\s*col\s*\*/#\1\n\2#p'
```

Using Basic regex:

```
echo "$s" |sed -n 's#.*/\([^/]*\.txt\).*"\([^"]*\)*"[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/\*[[:space:]]*col[[:space:]]*\*/#\1\n\2#p'
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to merge these 2 regular expressions in to one?

Comment: It works but still it works like an OR. Is it possible to make it work like AND where both expressions must match at the same time.

Comment: @Shahzad then grep won't be an intelligent choice.. added a sed solution

Answer (score 0):

To return **only** strings containing  `.txt` use `awk` with `-F`, `OFS` then pipe to `grep` invert:

```
awk -F'/|.txt|"' 'BEGIN { OFS = ".txt" } { print $2," "$4} | grep -v ','
```

**Result:**

```
xyz-ibl.txt simple
```

Comment: Even if there is no match, it prints .txt. Actually the input is coming from another grep which is to be pipped for further analysis. This means there are several lines which doesn't contain this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using awk

```
awk '{ match ($0, /\/([^.]+)(.txt)-.*"([^"]+)"/, fields); printf("%s%s %s\n", fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]); }'
```

The above does not consider the C style comment at the end. The following does.

```
awk '{ match ($0, /\/([^.]+)(.txt)-.*"([^"]+)", \/\* col \*\//, fields); printf("%s%s %s\n", fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]); }'
```